# ask, Command error J2ME LWUIT

Tags: forms, command, lwuit

I have an error to add a command button in my project using LWUIT 1.5

this is my code

initialitation :

```
Command backCommand = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 0);

f.addCommand(backCommand);
f.setCommandListener(this);
```

and this is an error

```
    cannot find symbol symbol: method addCommand
    (javax.microedition.lcdui.Command) location:
    class.com.sun.lwuit.Form
    --
```

please help me T.T, THANSK for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using `Command` object from the lcdui lib. Check your class imports and add the `Command`object from the LWUIT lib.

Comment: please do you think you could help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730176/j2me-how-to-parse-a-byte-array-into-xml-and-then-read-and-display-specific-data